# CSV copy entry if date is found in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, csv

I have a .csv file where in "Column 4" there are multiple data entries with different dates.

CSV:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4

20141122001,something,else,"12/29/2014 2:44PM - this is my message.  - Person 1
11/26/2014 11:36AM - PRE-PACKAGING

1-    Setting everything up
2-   Ready to go - Person 3"

20141216002,whatever,haha,"12/19/2014 12:13PM - PRE-PACKAGING - Person 3
12/17/2014 7:58PM - Person 3 has everything in order and is sending now - Person 1"
```

For each date and time found in Column 4, I would like to copy all columns of that row to a new row.

Ex:

```
20141216002,whatever,haha,"12/19/2014 12:13PM - PRE-PACKAGING - Person 3
12/17/2014 7:58PM - Person 3 has everything in order and is sending now - Person 1"
```

Is now two rows:

```
20141216002,whatever,haha,"12/19/2014 12:13PM - PRE-PACKAGING - Person 3"
20141216002,whatever,haha,"12/17/2014 7:58PM - Person 3 has everything in order and is sending now - Person 1"
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php

$string = "28.07.2012 something about this entry lol 28.12.2014 something else in this entry";

if(preg_match('/(.*)([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2,4})(.*)/', $string, $matches))
{
 $date = $matches[2];
}

echo $date;

//////////////////////

if (isset($date)) {

$newstring = str_replace($date,"",$string);

if(preg_match('/(.*)([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2,4})(.*)/', $newstring, $matches))
{
 $date2 = $matches[2];
}

}

echo "<br>";

echo $date2;

////////////////

echo "<br>";

$parts = parse_url($string);
$path_parts= explode($date, $parts[path]);
$user = $path_parts[1];
$user2 = $path_parts[0];
$user3 = $path_part[2];

echo $user . "<br>";
echo $user2 . "<br>";
echo $user3;
?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't help but think you're tackling this in the wrong place. It would be far easier to fix this at the point the CSV file is being generated rather than attempting to massage a broken format into something useful.

Comment: the csv is just an export from an excel spreadsheet. I do not have control at the time the spreadsheet is being created, only the ability to manipulate the data available.

Comment: What I decided to do as of right now is export to csv from excel, upload to a MySQL database, print the entries out and then copy the columns to new entries for each date found in column 4. This should work for now, but what would be another way to sufficiently tackle this?